# Bitmask position evaluation doesn't work in JS?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to evaluate if a given board state is end of game in Neutreeko (5x5 board, 3 connected horizontal, diagonal or vertical is a win) using JavaScript. Thanks to @Anonymous, I now know the bitmasks needed for it but I still can't get it working. Namely, when I try something like:

```
var x = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0];
if(x & (x >> 1) & (x >> 2) & 0x739ce7) console.log("success");
if(x & (x >> 5) & (x >> 10)) console.log("success");
```

I never get a success. Why is that so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is an array, which cannot be manipulated by JavaScript's bitwise operators. Change `x` to

```
var x = parseInt('1111111111111111111100000', 2);
```

and it should work. Note that JavaScript's bitwise operators only works with numbers between  -2<sup>31</sup> and 2<sup>31</sup> - 1, inclusive.

If you want to convert an array like your original one, you can do something like:

```
var x = parseInt([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0].join(''), 2);
```